# Dart analyzer in webstorm shows the message - unused import

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Please help! Dart analyzer in webstorm shows the message - unused import. I can't understand the reason and fix it. The image contains the file content - app_component.dart

On this line (*import 'src/click_me2_component.dart';*) in the file lib/app_component.dart I get a message  -  *info: Unused import: 'src/click_me2_component.dart'. (unused_import at [angular_app] lib\app_component.dart:1)*

**Image** - 
[app_component.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0IR0.jpg)

**lib/app_component.dart**

```dart
import 'src/click_me2_component.dart';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';


@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '''<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <click-me2></click-me2>''',
)
class AppComponent {
  var name = 'Angular';
}
```

**lib/src/click_me2_component.dart**

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'click-me2',
  template: '''
    <h1>No! .. Click me!</h1>
  ''',
)
class ClickMe2Component {
  String clickMessage = '';
  int _clicks = 1;

}
```

**analysis_options.yaml**

```
   analyzer:
  exclude: [build/**]
  errors:
    uri_has_not_been_generated: ignore
  plugins:
    - angular
```

linter:
  rules:
    - cancel_subscriptions
    - hash_and_equals
    - iterable_contains_unrelated_type
    - list_remove_unrelated_type
    - test_types_in_equals
    - unnecessary_const
    - unnecessary_new
    - unrelated_type_equality_checks
    - valid_regexps

Answer (score 0):

Thing is that **click_me2_component.dart** is not used indeed as  **app_component.dart** does not have anything from **click_me2_component.dart** used.

As I see you are trying to use "click-me2" component from **click_me2_component.dart**. In order to do that right you also need to add appropriate directive annotation, otherwise it will not work:

```dart
@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '''<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <click-me2></click-me2>''',
  directives: [
    ClickMe2Component,
  ],
)
class AppComponent {}
```

After you add directive referencing **ClickMe2Component**, you will notice that **click_me2_component.dart** is not unused anymore ;)